# About a polynomial in two variables

Tags: polynomials

It is well known that the polynomial

$ AX^2+BX+C $

is a perfect square when its discriminant

$ D=B^2-4AC=0 $

Is there a similar algorithm to check when the polynomial

$ AX^2+BXY+CY^2+DX+EY+F $

is a perfect square too?

Answer (score 0):

If we want $AX^2+BXY+CY^2+DX+EY+F=(GX+HY+J)^2$, we can just expand the square to get $G^2X^2+2GHXY+H^2Y^2+2GJX+2HJY+J^2$ and equate like terms.  You actually get a few tests: $B^2-4AC=0, D^2-4AF=0,E^2-4CF=0$, all of which have to pass.